# How to Find the GPS (Lat/Lon) Info from a Particular Point of an Image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I have got an image like this from an object detection model & I know the (x1, y1, x2, y2) value of every box.

I also know the GPS info of this image.

Now is there any way to calculate the latitude, longitude of each of the boxes from this (x1,y1, x2, y2) camera coordinates?

Any Python script or mathematical formula will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You'll also need to know the direction the camera is facing. Obviously they're all near the lat/long of the camera, but near in which direction?

Comment: This task is impossible, you only have the lat/long of your current image.. probably you can stimate the distance of each car from your camera but you can't get his gps position of each car.. only if your image is 2d like a satellital image.

Comment: @FreddyDaniel If I use a drone image from the top, is it possible?

Comment: @MSalters The direction means E N W this one?

Comment: @FreddyDaniel: That's of course nonsense. You can safely assume the height of the car (0 meters above road). Hence it's a matter of projection. Each pixel of the camera corresponds to a different angle;  a different direction in which in the camera looks. Draw a line through the camera and see where it intersects the ground plane. It's a bit of math, that's all. The main thing is that you need those directions for every pixel, staring with the rough direction (indeed N S E W)

Comment: @IFTEKHARIASIF could be.. the military drones send the gps position of the target to the missiles of this way the missile can arrive his target.

Comment: I have similar use case were you able to solve the issue ?

Comment: @Sunil Unfortunately no. I tried an alternative solution later.